# Use Map as property of model in Play

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I'm trying to use a Map as a type for one of my models properties. Let's take these two classes for example:

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends Model {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "name")
    public Map<String, Bar> bars;

    public String name;

}

@Entity
public class Bar extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    public Foo foo;

    public String name;
}
```

Very simplified of course, but that's the basic idea.
So what I'm trying to achieve is get a map with Bars as values and the names as their keys into Foo.

Now I want to utilize Fixture to load some data from this YAML file:

```
Foo(foo1):
    name: Foo1

Foo(foo2):
    name: Foo2

Bar(bar1):
    name: Bar1
    foo: foo1

Bar(bar2):
    name: Bar2
    foo: foo1
```

No problems so far, this works like a charm. Now if I try to change bar2 to `foo: foo2`, I get this Exception:

```
play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Cannot load fixture initial-data.yml: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: models.Foo.bars
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:166)
    at Invocation.Job(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load fixture initial-data.yml: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: models.Foo.bars
    at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:221)
    at jobs.Bootstrap.doJob(Bootstrap.java:18)
    at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:55)
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:157)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: models.Foo.bars
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:798)
    at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:47)
    at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:205)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: models.Foo.bars
    at org.hibernate.engine.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795)
    ... 6 more    

at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:795)
... 6 more
```

Of course I tried to google it but couldn't find any solution for my case. Any ideas on that? Funnily enough, I can go and change the values in the database afterwards and assign bar2 to foo1 and it all works perfectly fine, so I can't be too wrong...

Help would be much appreciated :)

Best,
kalarzo

Comment: You may try posting this question to play framework google group at http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework, they are very responsive...

Comment: I asked this "very similar" - identical question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508068/how-to-debug-found-two-representations-of-same-collection). Check out [what worked for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521408/11236).

Answer (score 2):

I tryed your code today and it worked without problems. Which play version do you use? I use 1.2.3.

Maybe the plugin [association](http://www.playframework.org/modules/associations-1.0.1/home) solves that problem, because that is what I'm using in background. 
Please let me know if an upgrade helped you.

Follows standard play module installation procedure:

```
play install associations
```

Add the following line to your **dependencies.yml** replacing 1.0 with desired version:

```
require:
    - play -> associations 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in v1.2.3 with Fixtures. Strangely if I didn't define a fixture below the one with the bi-directional Map OneToMany relationship there wasn't a problem. I also had a problem in one of my controllers if I didn't setup the bi-directional relationship completely. It does seem to be directly related to using a Map in a bi-directional OneToMany relationship. I switched to a Set and the problem went away. In the end I managed to resolve the situation without reverting to a Set by upgrading to v1.2.4RC2. I had a quick look through the change list in v1.2.4RC2 but couldn't spot anything that directly mentioned fixing this issue but something must have been resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the:

```
@MapKey(name = "name")
```

Comment: I'm assuming the user put it there on purpose.